# Using custom authentication handler with 2 auth methods: SSO JWT token and app specific method

Tags: c#, authentication, single-sign-on

I have a gateway API in .NET 6.0.0 (using Ocelot) that needs to authenticate users based on either the SSO (JWT generated and authenticated using Azure Authority in the token) or the special id generated by our app ecosystem for users that use the standard login method. Ocelot only allows specifying one AuthenticationProviderKey per endpoint. Because of that, I wanted to create a custom authentication handler that would authenticate a route based on whether there is a JWT token or the special id present in the request. The problem happens when it comes to moving SSO to that custom handler. Since it's generated by an external source and the app uses the configuration from Microsoft for that, I have no idea how to move it to the custom handler. The current state of the Program.cs - the part that handles token authentication:

```
var authenticationProviderKey = "AzureAdJwtBearer";
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(authenticationProviderKey, opt =>
    {
        opt.Audience = config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:Audience");
        opt.Authority = $"address1" + config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId"); ;
        opt.MetadataAddress = $"address2" + config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId") + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    });
```

What I tried to do but I can't figure out - Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultScheme = TwoAuthSchemeOptions.Name)
    .AddScheme<TwoAuthsSchemeOptions, TwoAuthsHandler>(TwoAuthsSchemeOptions.Name, options => { });
```

TwoAuthsSchemeOptions.cs:

```
    public class TwoAuthsSchemeOptions:AuthenticationSchemeOptions
        {
            public const string Name = "TwoAuthsScheme";
        }
```

TwoAuthsHandler.cs:

```
public class TwoAuthsHandler : AuthenticationHandler<TwoAuthsSchemeOptions>
    {
        public TwoAuthsHandler(IOptionsMonitor<TwoAuthsSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var loginTypeHeader = Request.Headers["logintype"].ToString();

        switch (loginTypeHeader)
        {
            case "sso":
                try
                {
                    //I would like to use the authentication here that is used by default when setting up the original Program.cs
                    //in this case

                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("User authentication failed or session expired"));
                }
            case "special":
                try
                {
                    //Special id authentication that I have implemented

                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
                }
                catch
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("User authentication failed or session expired"));
                }
            default:
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("User authentication failed or session expired"));
        } 
    }
}
```

Based on the case I either want that special id authentication or the SSO authentication however I can't use this:

```
tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret")),
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidIssuer = "someissuer",
                            ValidAudience = "someaudience",
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                        }, out SecurityToken securityToken);
```

Because the token comes from the outside, not from the app. All the authentication happens based on opt.Authority and opt.MetadataAddress option for SSO in the original setup so I don't see how I can implement it myself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the custom authentication handler to handle the `special` authentication.
2. Define a policy schema and set the `ForwardDefaultSelector` delegate
3. Use the policy schema name in `Ocelot.json` file (`AuthSelector` in the example below)

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = ...;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = ...;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = ...;
    })
    .AddPolicyScheme(
        authenticationScheme: "AuthSelector",
        displayName: "AuthSelector",
        options => options.ForwardDefaultSelector = httpContext =>
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("xxx"))
            {
                return "special";
            }

            return "AzureAdJwtBearer";
        })
    .AddJwtBearer("AzureAdJwtBearer", ...)
    .AddScheme<SpecialAuthOptions, SpecialAuthHandler>("special", options => { });
```